# Type Testing Elements of a List

Tags: python, list, testing, types

Can somebody please provide some commentary on the following results.  I am particularly confused by what I am actually doing when I write: alist = [None]*5  in #1
and why the 'is' statement is False , but isinstance is True in #3
Much appreciated.

```
#1
>>> alist = [None]*5

>>> alist

[None, None, None, None, None]

>>> type(alist[0])

<type 'NoneType'>

>>> type(alist[0]) is None
False

#2
>>> alist = [int]*5
>>> alist

[<type 'int'>, <type 'int'>, <type 'int'>, <type 'int'>, <type 'int'>]

>>> type(alist[0]) is int

False

>>> isinstance(alist[0],int)

False

#3
>>> alist = [0.0]*5

>>>type(alist[0])

<type 'float'>

>>> alist[0] is float

False

>>> isinstance(alist[0],float)

True
```

Comment: the `is` operator is used for identity checking, it only returns `True` if it's the exact same object with the same ID.

Comment: You're not cheating at your homework, are you?

Answer (score 2):

> what I am actually doing when I write: alist = [None]*5 in

You are calling the * operator on a list.
See here: http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#sequence-types-str-unicode-list-tuple-bytearray-buffer-xrange

> why the 'is' statement is False

because `<type 'NoneType'>` is not `None`, it's the type of `None`.

> isinstance is True in #3

because `alist[0]` is an instance of the type `float`. Wasn't that dificult, was it?

Comment: This is not for homework Sebastian.  But could you elaborate a little on "the type of None"?  What does that mean? in #3 "isinstance" is True but "is" is False.  Why?  I am sure these two are related but still confused. thanks

Comment: @user1816858: `None` is the value of the sole instance of the built-in `types.NoneType` class.

Comment: @user1816858: In #3, `0.0` is an instance of type `float`, but it is not _the_ type `float`. types are also objects (instances of type `type`) in Python.

Comment: Thanks @martineau.  Im 100% on this now.